# How can I make my form field have a background image?

Tags: css, forms, background, field, transparent

I added `background: transparent;` to the form field, however that also includes the image I'm trying to attach. When I use just the image, all I see is the regular form field. The field itself is like a sketchy underline, so that's why I need the image versus CSS styling. Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

*Update! I couldn't get my images to show up because I hadn't set the height / width on the field itself. But the underline is showing up. The image itself is a transparent png, but the white background of the input field still persists. Can anyone tell me how to make it transparent with the png on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
background-image:url(xxx.png);
border:none;
background-color:transparent;
```

Not only "background"

Answer (score 0):

I added RGBA to the background and set the alpha to '0'! I hope this helps someone else out there. :)